# Adding versioning to the Entity class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an old code base with 2 Entity classes (suppose with 10 measure). Old Functionality work like whenever u upload a Excel file it gonna parse the file and map to these entity class. Now as per new requirements  Every year I am getting more measure added to these entity classes and getting new Excel file with 5 measure. How can I add versioning based on every year or how can I do mapping to the entity class every year from only one base Entity Class. Or how can I introduce this functionality without changing the design

Example of entity class-

```
[DataColumnAttribute]
public StatusLkup Insurance { get; set; }

[DataColumnAttribute]
public Code Status { get; set; }

[DataColumnAttribute]
public string test1 { get; set; }
```

Example of Excel file

Row 1 - Insurance, states, test1
Row 2 -         5,     Co,  test

Next year suppose 2 more new measure added to an entity class

```
[DataColumnAttribute]
public StatusLkup Insurance { get; set; }

[DataColumnAttribute]
public Code Status { get; set; }

[DataColumnAttribute]
public string test1 { get; set; }  

[DataColumnAttribute]
public string test2 { get; set; }  

[DataColumnAttribute]
public string test3 { get; set; }
```

Next year excel file

Row 1 - test1, test2
Row 2 -   12,    11

Comment: you can have a single model with all fields from all versions and use only those fileds which are related to the version of the exact object (version can be stored separately). so when a new version comes, you would need just to extend your existing model, and add a logic which processes it.

Answer (score 2):

Since each year is a different, but based on the previous, one can create `Interfaces` which will define (*version*) the years.

*One can create interfaces regardless of the differences, but the point being, it versions the data*.

By doing that you will version the data and be able to use/sort it accordingly with no changes in current code, just adding new code each year.

---

**Example**

Two interfaces and the second one inheirits from the first:

```
public interface IYear1
{
    int Test1 { get; set;}
}

public interface IYear2 : IYear1
{
    int Test2 { get; set;}
}
```

Then the classes derived:

```
public class Year1 : IYear1
{
    public int Test1 { get; set;}
}

public class Year2 : Year1, IYear2
{
    public int Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in code we can create/determine what year is being processed:

```
var year = new Year2() { Test1 = 1, Test2 = 2};

if (year is IYear2)
    Console.WriteLine("Year 2 Found");

if (year is IYear1)
    Console.WriteLine("Year 1 Found");
```

The result is we identified two versions that are being used:

```
Year 2 Found
Year 1 Found
```